# Van I increase my facebook fan page 'likes' through some 'action' invoked on a 'object' within an external website

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to increase the number of 'likes' on a facebook company page or an band's facebook page via invoking an 'action' on an 'object' within an external website.

Say I've got a website that produces news on bands and we create a button/object called 'Connect with Artist' and on clicking this it would link the user to the artist facebook page and increase the artists 'likes'.

Is this possible through Open Graph?

Answer (score 2):

This is something that is a violation of Facebook's ToS, and will get you in a lot more trouble than you would expect. Best you can do here is add a "Like" button on the outside page, which users can click on to be taken to the band's page, where they can then like it on facebook, as per this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/